# Vue Cli init my-app raises "too many arguments"

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have installed the new vue-cli 3 using instructions on their website

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

I try to check what version I have:

`vue --help` (according to their documentation this command should work)

but I get

`cd: string not in pwd: /home/jedrek/workspace/VueJS`

I removed the old version:

`npm uninstall vue-cli -g`

Reinstalled the new one and I still the same issue.
I can't even generate any project, I am getting `too many arguments` error

`vue init webpack-simple my_app #=> cd: too many arguments`

I have checked for system aliases in my zsh but I didn't find any I don't recall setting any.

What do I miss?

Comment: did you try `vue create my_app`

Comment: Yes, it raises the same error: `vue create my_app #=> cd: too many arguments`

Comment: try to uninstall vue cli and reinstall it using `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli `

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: I don't know why you get this error. But try to create the project by `vue ui` command.

Comment: It doesn't work either, I get this error `cd: string not in pwd: /home/jedrek/workspace/VueJS`

Comment: Are you using `zsh` as your shell?

Comment: yes, I di use zsh as my shell

Comment: In that case, there could be a problem with your `.zshrc`. Replace your current config with the one which is sure to work (maybe available as an example on `zsh`'s site). And then try.